# How to await user input with javascripts async/await syntax?

Tags: javascript, async-await, dom-events

**edit:** ATTENTION: *following the recommendation by user Barmar in their comment below i will vote to close this more or less opinion/best practise oriented question. I did not delete it but voted to close for there have been answers and productive comments with upvotes already. I reposted this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250351/how-to-await-user-input-with-javascripts-async-await-syntax-in-a-more-functional*

I love async/await and Promises since I got my hands on them. And I might be overdoing it, but it feels like there should be a good and readable way to utilize async/await to get a little closer to a flow like, functionalISH programming style.

I would love to not have to only use async/await to wait for web resources to come back but also to wait for user input when I await it.

So far i have some code working similar to this shortened demo where I wrap a one time only EventListener into a Promise:

```js
//// MAIN ///////

(async function(){

    //...do some async await stuff here... fetching stuff from a server
    // let services = await fetch(...) for example
    let services = [{url:"x",label:"1"},{url:"y",label:"2"},{url:"z",label:"3"}]


    let service_chosen = await showServicesToUserAndAwaitInput(services); 
    console.log("service_chosen:",service_chosen);
    // ... go on....
})()

//// END MAIN /////


async function showServicesToUserAndAwaitInput(services){
    
    if (services.length < 1){return null}

    let choice = null;
    
    let serviceList = document.querySelector("#serviceList");
    
    // show list element
    serviceList.classList.remove("hidden") 

    // create some elements for the user to interact with
    for (let service of services){
        let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        button.innerHTML = service.label;
        button.addEventListener("click",function(){
          document.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('serviceChosen', { detail:service })
          )
        });
        serviceList.appendChild(button);
    }
    
    // returns promise with one time only event listener
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
        document.addEventListener("serviceChosen",function(e){
            serviceList.classList.add("hidden") // hide again for we are done
            resolve(e.detail)
        },{ once: true })
    })
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="serviceList" class="hidden">

</div>
```

But something about this use of the EventListener bugs me. Also: I use a promise that always resolves, which also seems strange.

On the upside: I get to read the code top to bottom and can follow the user flow within the MAIN without having to chase down events, callbacks and so on.

Yet, it feels like I am reinventing something somebody else might have already normed. So:

Is there a better way to achieve this? Are there best practices to work with user interactions or other DOM events in a async and/or thenable way?

Comment: i am happy to delete or modify this question if it is poorly written or missplaced. but i would love to get a reason for downvotes, so I can avoid doing the same mistake twice.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but questions about best practices are considered opinion-based and off-topic. Questions about redesigning or refactoring working code are more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Comment: I will upvote, only because I don't agree with SO "opinion-based" policy.

Comment: That said, I don't think I've ever seen anyone use `async/await` for processing externally-initiated events. It's mainly used when the program initiates an action that finishes asynchronously, such as an API request.

Comment: The Deno HTTP module does something like this.  It makes you `await` the next request.

Comment: That's because these are more intuitively viewed as function calls, and it's only the design of JavaScript that forces us to implement them asynchronously.

Comment: I would propose to use RXJS instead, to solve this problem which is trivial with that library. You can see [an example here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)

Comment: thanks @Barmar. that explanation makes sense. i will move it to Code Review and edit it to point to your comment as reference for there are already answers/discussion provided.

Comment: thanks @Hakier! this actually seems to answer my issue (skippin over their docs). If you like, post an example under https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250351/how-to-await-user-input-with-javascripts-async-await-syntax-in-a-more-functional 
otherwise: i will check this library out. Sad though that it aint native. external stuff always makes code so much harder for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example of your code without async/await and custom events. Progress is done simply by calling appropriate functions. User input is handled by the click event, which listenes for user interaction and triggers appropriate functions.

```js
//// MAIN ///////
let services = [{url:"x",label:"1"},{url:"y",label:"2"},{url:"z",label:"3"}]

showServicesToUserAndAwaitInput(services);
//// END OF MAIN ////

function showServicesToUserAndAwaitInput(services){
        
  if (services.length < 1){return null}

  let choice = null;

  let serviceList = document.querySelector("#serviceList");

  // show list element
  serviceList.classList.remove("hidden") 

  // create some elements for the user to interact with
  for (let service of services){
      let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      button.innerHTML = service.label;
      button.addEventListener("click",function(){
        chooseService(service);
      });
      serviceList.appendChild(button);
  }
  
  function chooseService(service) {
    let service_chosen = service;
    console.log("service_chosen:",service_chosen);
    
    hideServices();
  }
  
  function hideServices() {
    serviceList.classList.add("hidden") // hide again for we are done
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
      visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="serviceList" class="hidden">

</div>
```